# Which PGN tags are supported on Chess SE?

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

When I paste such a PGN from a site, it does not show as a chess PGN viewer. This is an example PGN:

```
[Event "Daily HyperBullet Arena"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/kuvnBssO"]
[Date "2018.07.20"]
[Round "-"]
[White "Kulkid"]
[Black "WaisKamal"]
[Result "0-1"]
[UTCDate "2018.07.20"]
[UTCTime "18:41:55"]
[WhiteElo "2016"]
[BlackElo "2107"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "-9"]
[BlackRatingDiff "+8"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "30+0"]
[ECO "D44"]
[Opening "Queen's Gambit Declined: Vienna Variation, Quiet Variation"]
[Termination "Normal"]
[Annotator "lichess.org"]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 Nf6 3. Nc3 e6 4. Nf3 dxc4 5. e3 { D44 Queen's Gambit Declined: Vienna Variation, Quiet Variation } Be7 6. Bxc4 O-O 7. Bd3 Nbd7 8. O-O b6 9. Re1 Bb7 10. a3 Bxf3 11. b4 Bxd1 12. Rxd1 c5 13. Bb2 cxd4 14. exd4 Qc7 15. Ne2 Rac8 16. Rac1 Qb7 17. Rb1 Rc7 18. f3 Rfc8 19. Ng3 h6 20. Ne4 Nxe4 21. Bxe4 Qb8 22. Bd3 Bf6 23. Ba6 Rd8 24. Be2 b5 25. Kf2 a6 26. Bc1 Nf8 27. Be3 Rdd7 28. Rdc1 Rxc1 29. Rxc1 Qd8 30. Rd1 Bxd4 31. Bxd4 Rxd4 32. Rc1 Rd2 33. Re1 Ng6 34. Ke3 f5 35. Kf2 Nf4 36. Kg3 Nxe2+ 37. Kf2 Qd4+ 38. Kf1 Qg1# { Black wins by checkmate. } 0-1
```

I thought some tags are not supported by the PGN viewer. What tags are supported, or, is it an issue with my PGN?

Comment: For the PGN viewer to appear, you first need to indent the PGN four spaces (which can be done using the "preformatted text" option in the editor). Did you do that, and it still didn't appear?

Comment: It is indented but still does not appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the PGN viewer to appear, you need to include

> [fen ""]

in the PGN header. I just tested the following on the main site (the viewer isn't active on meta), and it worked:

```
[Event "Daily HyperBullet Arena"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/kuvnBssO"]
[Date "2018.07.20"]
[Round "-"]
[White "Kulkid"]
[Black "WaisKamal"]
[Result "0-1"]
[UTCDate "2018.07.20"]
[UTCTime "18:41:55"]
[WhiteElo "2016"]
[BlackElo "2107"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "-9"]
[BlackRatingDiff "+8"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "30+0"]
[ECO "D44"]
[Opening "Queen's Gambit Declined: Vienna Variation, Quiet Variation"]
[Termination "Normal"]
[Annotator "lichess.org"]
[fen ""]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 Nf6 3. Nc3 e6 4. Nf3 dxc4 5. e3 { D44 Queen's Gambit Declined: Vienna Variation, Quiet Variation } Be7 6. Bxc4 O-O 7. Bd3 Nbd7 8. O-O b6 9. Re1 Bb7 10. a3 Bxf3 11. b4 Bxd1 12. Rxd1 c5 13. Bb2 cxd4 14. exd4 Qc7 15. Ne2 Rac8 16. Rac1 Qb7 17. Rb1 Rc7 18. f3 Rfc8 19. Ng3 h6 20. Ne4 Nxe4 21. Bxe4 Qb8 22. Bd3 Bf6 23. Ba6 Rd8 24. Be2 b5 25. Kf2 a6 26. Bc1 Nf8 27. Be3 Rdd7 28. Rdc1 Rxc1 29. Rxc1 Qd8 30. Rd1 Bxd4 31. Bxd4 Rxd4 32. Rc1 Rd2 33. Re1 Ng6 34. Ke3 f5 35. Kf2 Nf4 36. Kg3 Nxe2+ 37. Kf2 Qd4+ 38. Kf1 Qg1# { Black wins by checkmate. } 0-1
```

That's usually just used for inputting an initial position (in FEN notation) that differs from the chess start position, and otherwise PGN readers will default to using the start position; in the case of the site's PGN viewer, it's needed explicitly even when starting at the beginning of the game because that particular part of the header is what triggers the viewer to display on the site.